# What counts into the cumulative CPU time for a bash process?

Tags: cpu, ps

What counts into the cumulative CPU time for a bash process? Only when bash is parsing all kinds of commands before actually executing them, and when bash is running builtin command and function definitions and calls?

I have a bash shell having been running for days in a terminal emulator.
Why is the cumulative CPU time for the bash process only 2 seconds (or 2 minutes)?

```
$ ps $$
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
22135 pts/12   Ss     0:02 bash
```

In `ps` manpage:

> `cputime     TIME`      cumulative CPU time, "[DD-]hh:mm:ss" format.

Thanks.

Comment: Because time spent waiting for input (eg at the command prompt) isn't using any CPU time.  The kernel knows the process is waiting and so doesn't schedule it for execution.

Comment: I guess that the bash time is: startup, sourcing startup files (like `.bashrc`), processing your input and starting new processes to do the actual work. Even shell scripts are run in forked processes. So in fact, the interactive shell is mostly idle.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/ps/output.c#L557), it is the sum of the user-time (time spent in usermode-code) + system-time (time spent in kernel-space / syscalls).

So when bash is just idling it is in neither, because it is not actually executing anything.